# Override res.json function signature with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to override the `res.json()` method in Express. I wrote a middleware that looks something like this:

```js
import type { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

// Middleware to override res.json
export const myMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.json = function (customArg: CustomType, body: Record<string, any>) {
    // ... my custom code
  };

  next();
};
```

However I'm running into issues with typing. I've added an `index.d.ts` file that looks like this:

```js
// index.d.ts
import type { Send } from 'express';

declare global {
  namespace Express {

    // This works with Request!
    export interface Request {
      json: Send<Record<any, any>, Response<Record<string, any>>>;
    }
  
    // This does NOT work!
    export interface Response {
      json(customArg: CustomType, body: Record<string, any>): Send<any, Response<any, Record<string, any>>>;
    }

  }
}
```

I've also tried importing `Response` from `express-serve-static-core` which looked something like this:

```js
// index.d.ts
import type { Send } from 'express';
import type { Response } from 'express-serve-static-core';

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    // ...
    // This still did not work!
    declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
      export interface Response {
        json(customArg: CustomType, body: Record<string, any>): Send<any, Response<any, Record<string, any>>>;
      }
    }
  }
}
```